# How to make an image button that displays a different image when clicked? (android, eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to make an image button that when clicked it displays a different image on the same page without going to any other page and also being able to add a button when this photo is displayed to save the photo or to view it using the device default photo viewer, something like when you make a class and you type in the application settings

like that:

```
<activity
       ....
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >     
        <intent-filter>
            ....
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So if you could help me that would be great, Thanks

Comment: This may be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013003/how-to-change-button-background-when-button-state-is-changed/25013267#25013267

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a selector:

In your ImageButton's activity's layout xml:

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/mybutton"
android:src="@drawable/button_selector"/>
```

button_selector.xml in drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_clicked="true" 
  android:drawable="@drawable/button_clicked" /> <!-- clicked --> 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" /> <!-- default --> 

</selector>
```

Comment: so does this selector is only set to one image button or all of them in the same xml, and if only for one image button how to make one for every image button

Comment: only one just set the src tag on the image button you want

Comment: I'am really sorry but I don't understand quite well, can you explain it again.

Comment: okay so in your layout file for your activity add the android:src tag to the declaration of your image button, make sure you have a file called button_selector.xml in you drawable folder and change button_clicked to the drawable for you clicked image and button_default for the drawable of you unclicked image

Comment: so I'am going to make a xml file for every image button that I want it to do display an image when clicked.

Comment: you will make a selector xml file for each image and set it as the src for each button